# No access to apache docker server

Tags: mongodb, apache, docker, glassfish

in my docker image I need to run an Apache Server to deploy my website, a glassfish server for deploying the corresponding backend and MongoDB on which the backend connects.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
FROM glassfish:latest
FROM mongo:3.6


COPY /backend_war_exploded /usr/local/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/backend_war_exploded
COPY /backend_war_exploded /usr/local/glassfish4/bin/backend_war_exploded
COPY /dist /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

After building the image I run and start it with:

```
docker run -dit --name application -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -p 27017:27017 applicationimg
docker start application
```

When I try to access via `http://localhost:80` it delivers the code: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Same for the backend but I can access `mongodb` on port `27017`. When I am commenting out the `FROM` tags in my `dockerfile` and run everything separately it just works fine. Does somebody see the mistake? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I followed your suggestion and created rewrote the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY /dist /var/www/html/
COPY /backend_war_exploded /glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/backend_war_exploded

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y unzip
RUN wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1.2/release/glassfish-4.1.2.zip

RUN unzip glassfish-4.1.2.zip

RUN cd /glassfish4/bin/ && ./asadmin start-domain domain1




EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080
```

The webserver starts up and is accesable via `localhost:80` but the glassfish server start while building the image but when running the docker image it is not started anymore. When I am accessing the container via `docker exec` I can navigate to glassfish and start it up manually. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to depend on on `FROM` only and add the other tools through `RUN` steps. or use single image for each application and connect them together through [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) or by creating a `docker-compose.yml` which will be easier, you can check it through [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/). Using multiple `FROM` does not mean that you are going to have all 3 in 1.

For more information about how to create Dockerfile and How to deploy your application with multiple containers you can check the [get started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) tutorial from Docker

In order to run multiple service inside one container you need to use a service manager like Supervisor. Check the following link for more details: [Multi-Service Container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

Comment: I am very new to docker, could you please give an example

Comment: @ChinaeduOnwukwe you can start through here https://docs.docker.com/get-started/ you can find more valuable information as a start for Docker ^_^

Comment: @ChinaeduOnwukwe Does the current solution answers your question or you need further explanation ?